# How to print "string" from Solidity in React?

Tags: web3js, dapps, react

My smart contract function is :

```
function sNName(uint z)public view returns(string memory) {
    return abc[xyz[z].name];
}
```

Where abc represents a mapping (bytes32 => string)

In my .js file, I called the function like this:

```
for(x=0 ;x < t; x++)
{
  n = await marketplaceContract.methods.sNName(x).call().toString();
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    cart: [...prevState.cart, n]
  }));
}
```

When I try to output cart, I get :

```
[object Promise]
```

I expected a string cos I have used await. Is there any mistake in using it inside a loop?

Please help.

Comment: As far as I can tell you are calling .toString to the promise and after that awaiting it, which doesn't make sense. Try `n = (await marketplaceContract.methods.sNName(x).call()).toString();`

Comment: Thanks @LauriPeltonen. I get your point. But after doing that, there's no output. I mean now it's completely blank.

Comment: But when I am storing in cart[] a fixed string, in place of n and then printing it, it's printing the fixed string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
n = await marketplaceContract.methods.sNName(x).call().toString()
```

To this:

```
n = (await marketplaceContract.methods.sNName(x).call()).toString()
```

BTW, I believe that `n` is a string already before you call `toString()`.

If I'm right, then you can simply do:

```
n = await marketplaceContract.methods.sNName(x).call()
```

Your problem in general is that the `toString()` part takes precedence over the `await` part, so you are essentially trying to apply `toString` on a `Promise` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the part about what my `toString()` is doing. I did as you told. In my front-end, nothing is showing up when I am returning in my `render()`. It's really curious.

Comment: @ShaileshMishra: You're welcome. The question here is not about your front-end (and it would be missing a lot of context & details if it were). So I suggest that you post it as a separate question.

Comment: Okay sure will do that